# redshift - No adjustment method 'randr'

Tags: redshift

I have installed redshift 1.10 and created its config file in

```
~/.config/redshift.conf
```

as shown in http://jonls.dk/redshift/, but when I execute redshift I get a:

```
No adjustment method 'randr'
```

So I list the methods with:

```
redshift -m list
```

and `dummy` is the only method listed.

so how I do install or configure the other adjustment methods?

Comment: Is there are reason why you're not using the version from the repository? Worked for me out of the box.

Comment: What hardware do you have and what video driver are you using ? "Your graphics driver and X server needs to either support at least RANDR version 1.3 or the VidMode extension"

Comment: i am using a geforce 210 with the default ubuntu trusty driver nouveau. @bodhi.zazen

Comment: can you post the output of xrandr =)

Comment: i have uploaded the xrandr output -  @bodhi.zazen

Comment: Aright, I do not see any obvious problem. See https://answers.launchpad.net/redshift/+question/235109 and http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9003 , especially the last answer setting your location.

Comment: I try that with no sucess,

it seems there is a problem with the installation because i dont see redshift listed in synaptic neither in software center, but in terminal i write:

which redshift and returns:

/usr/local/bin/redshift

- so how can i remove redshift 1.10 ? @bodhi.zazen

Comment: It sounds as if your video card is not supported. Removing depends on if the make file has an uninstall option or not.

Comment: i dont see any info about uninstalling it, have to delete it manuallly? how do i remove all the dependencies installed? 
(i tried purge remove and it says redshift is not installed) @bodhi.zazen

Comment: i solved the problem, thanks for your help @bodhi.zazen

Comment: @Ivanyosan: If you need help uninstalling this version of redshift, please open a new question.

Comment: @Ivanyosan: what did you do to solve the problem?

Comment: The answer was deleted eventhough it worked for me. @Fabby
here it is : 
http://pastebin.com/N2wbkrTY

Comment: There you go! answer undeleted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

First you have to download the .zip version of redshift from:

https://github.com/jonls/redshift

Then you have to install the dependencies:

```
autotools, gettext
intltool, libtool
libdrm (Optional, for DRM support)
libxcb, libxcb-randr (Optional, for RandR support)
libX11, libXxf86vm (Optional, for VidMode support)
geoclue (Optional, for geoclue support)
python3, pygobject, pyxdg (Optional, for GUI support)
appindicator (Optional, for Ubuntu-style GUI status icon)
```

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/blob/master/HACKING.md)

And now you do the installation:

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential libxcb-randr0-dev
   ./bootstrap
   ./configure --enable-randr --prefix=$HOME/redshift/root \
       --with-systemduserunitdir=$HOME/.config/systemd/user
    make
    make install
```

and now:

```
$HOME/redshift/root/bin/redshift-gtk
```

I am in Colombia so the the config file I use is: (lat:lon from Colombia)

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=6500
temp-night=4500

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0
;brightness=1.0
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night since version 1.8.
brightness-day=1.0
brightness-night=1.0
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel individually)
gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
;location-provider=geoclue

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
lat=4.610078
lon=-74.082336

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the second screen.
[randr]
screen=0
```

**And that solved my problem**

Comment: -1 OP isn't asking how to install redshift but about video driver compatibility issues.

Comment: There you go!  Undeleted, edited and visible! (oh, and upvoted!)

Comment: For me this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may have created a `redshift.conf` file. Edit that very file and at bottom change `screen=1` to `screen=0`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I had Ubuntu 14.04 and nVidia Geforce 310M driver. redshift worked fine. Yesterday I have totally removed and installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 and the recommended graphic card driver by Ubuntu. Now redshift does not work.
I tried lots of things. The only worked solution (not for redshift) is:

```
xrandr --current --output LVDS-0 --gamma 0.1:1.0:1.0
```

which changes display colour.

Comment: but that may only change brightness and not color temperature. @Mir Saman